# how to pass arguments to a function using a predefined SIGNAL in PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt4, signals-slots

lets suppose you have 3 QRadioButtons instances inside a class

```
self.Option1 = QRadioButton()
self.Option2 = QRadioButton()
self.Option2 = QRadioButton()
```

(for brevity i didn't wrote the entire script)
and you want to use them to execute a particular function when the user clicks it, so you do

```
self.connect(self.Option1,SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.myFunction)
self.connect(self.Option2,SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.myFunction)
self.connect(self.Option2,SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.myFunction)
```

How do i pass arguments to to myFunction so it knows wich of the QRadioButtons was clicked by the user? so i can do stuff like

```
def myFunction(choice):
   if choice == Option1:
       do something
   if choice == Option2:
       do something
```

Right now i have 3 functions, each for every connect like this

```
self.connect(self.Option1,SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.myFunction1)
self.connect(self.Option2,SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.myFunction2)
self.connect(self.Option2,SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.myFunction2)
```

And this approach works just fine, but you can see how quickly the code can grow because with every widget i add i'll have to write at least one new function or modify the existing ones, its going to be a maintainance nightmare(not to mention that it looks ugly and it prevents code reuse).

A quick visit to google got me this:

```
    self.label = QLabel(" ")

    self.connect(self, SIGNAL("didSomething"),
                 self.update_label)
    self.do_something()

def do_something(self):
    self.emit(SIGNAL("didSomething"), "important", "information")

def update_label(self, value1, value2):
    self.label.setText(value1 + " " + value2)
```

(again i didnt include the entire script but you can check it out [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/pyqt-how-to-pass-arguments-while/))
What he did was creating a method to define a custom emitter that sends arguments when emitted and then activated it manually using

```
self.do_something()
```

So naturally, the connect function picks this emition and pass the arguments to the function update_label, partially achieving what i want to do. But he is doing it manually, is there a way to automatically "intercept" standard signals(for example the clicked() signal QRadioButtons emit) and add arguments to it, so they get passed to a function to work with them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Qt solution of this problem is QSignalMapper I think. But I had the same problem before, and I figured out using "partial" function is simplier. Use it like that:

```
from functools import partial

self.connect(self.Option1,SIGNAL("clicked()"), partial(self.myFunction, 1))
self.connect(self.Option2,SIGNAL("clicked()"), partial(self.myFunction, 2))
self.connect(self.Option3,SIGNAL("clicked()"), partial(self.myFunction, 3))
```

For more info: http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Comment: This is definitely simpler that using QSignalMapper, i guess eventually i'll use it, but right now your solution works best, thank you.