# Passing arguments through QtGui.QAction to the triggered method

Tags: python, pyqt, qtgui

Let's say I have a method like:

```
def open(self, opt):
    if opt == True:
    ...
    if opt == False:
    ...
```

how do I pass the argument to it with *QtGui.QAction* like:

```
self.openAct = QtGui.QAction("O&pen", self, shortcut="Ctrl+O",
            statusTip="Opens a location", triggered=self.open)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer it is *from functools import partial*. It was in [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364291/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-function-using-a-predefined-signal-in-pyqt?rq=1).